# Launching C# program from another C# program

Tags: c#, .net, sdl, sdl-2

Due to me having knowledge of launching apps I am aware that you have multiple ways of launching an application in C# .NET, but I'm running into a issue that occurs when attempting to launch a SDL2 application.

I have attempted the following using the Process class to:

- Start the .exe file of the build.
- Start the application using "`cmd.exe /K`" or "`cmd.exe /c`" followed by "`exec`" or "`call`" or "`start`" followed by "`{path to file}`" or "`{path to batch file to launch the application}`". Launching the application via a batch file and CMD works fine. But, whenever I attempt to even launch the application (even in a new instance of Command-Prompt launched from cmd.exe /? start cmd.exe ?params) it will yield no result.

What I can observe is that the application tries to open. It takes forever to launch into the Window mode (starting the 3D environment). After a timeout it will either, render a couple of frames of a blank window before closing or close immediately after opening the window.

So my question is, does anyone have succesfully made a launcher application for a SDL app written in C# .NET? Or knows a way to debug this behaviour? Because unfortunately, the app does not send out a error message and since SDL safely closes the application I can't observe a crash either.

**Edit #1**

I'm not doing anything fancy with parameters as there shouldn't be any. I already have another one functioning that launches a normal C# application as my launcher requires to open 2 programs. 1 SLD application, 1 COM:VBA controlling application.
Given:

```
string audioSpectrumProgram = "AudioSpectrum.exe";
string audioSpectrumBatchProgram = "AudioSpectrum.bat";

private void BtnLaunchPPTApp_OnClick()
{
    //Powerpoint controlling application
    pVBAApp = Process.Start(presenterProgram, $"\"{this.path}\" {this.audioFormatParams[0]} {((this.ckboxGenerate.Checked) ? "--create" : "")} lang={this.languageCodesParams[this.cboxLanguage.SelectedIndex]}");
}
```

Method 1:

```
private void BtnLaunchSDLApp_OnClick()
{
    pVizualizer = Process.Start(audioSpectrumProgram); //file launched from local path (is correct)
}
```

Method 2:

```
pVizualizer = Process.Start(audioSpectrumBatchProgram); //file launched from local path (is correct)
```

Method 3:

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
FileInfo spectrumFileInfo = new FileInfo(audioSpectrumProgram);
if (spectrumFileInfo.Exists)
   info.Arguments = $"/c \"{spectrumFileInfo.FullName}\"";
pVizualizer = Process.Start(info);
```

Method 4:
based on senario of method 3. You don't have to parse arguments using ProcessStartInfo.

```
pVizualizer = Process.Start($"cmd.exe /K call \"{spectrumFileInfo.FullName}\"") //to observe what happens to the application
```

**Edit #2**

Not affected by changing the UseShellExecute to `true` or `false`

```
private void btnOpenVisualizer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FileInfo spectrumFileInfo = new FileInfo(audioSpectrumProgram);
        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(spectrumFileInfo.FullName);
        info.UseShellExecute = true;
        pVizualizer = new Process();
        pVizualizer.StartInfo = info;
        pVizualizer.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        pVizualizer.Exited += new EventHandler(myProcess_Exited);
        pVizualizer.Start();
    }

    private void myProcess_Exited(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
            $"Exit time    : {pVizualizer.ExitTime}\n" +
            $"Exit code    : {pVizualizer.ExitCode}\n"
            );
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Ryan and welcome to StackOverflow. I think there might be something wrong with the code which is used for launching the process. Could you please share that code to allow us to help you?

Comment: Please add code you are using and not working. I suspect you passing parameters incorrectly.

Comment: It should technically be as simple as just launching the app as it does not utilise any params except for launching an Exec or Batch file from CMD instead of launching the process directly.

Comment: Oh yeah would like to emphasize that the application does in fact start. It's just that the SDL application that runs fine on its own and launched from a batch file or command prompt. It simply refuses to open a 3D environment when launched from another C# application, even if the LAUNCHER application is executing a call to start the process from an newly made CMD instance in C#. And no it can run side by side other C# applications if you'd think that this is the issue.

Comment: Have you tried to set [UseShellExecute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute?view=netframework-4.7.2) to false?

Comment: Unfortunately it has no effect on the way it boots.

Comment: Thanks however on the lead ... did find a way to redirect the output (totally have had forgotten about this). It has led me to an error with "System.IO.StreamReader" for some odd reason. Annoyingly this is the only string i get before it crashes though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok For Future reference:
Pathing to the files can be correct and everything might be in order but if you are using DLLs for imports. Change the process's working directory.

The project will run, libs can "sometimes" be found but can cause a weird unknown bug like this one. So the most optimal way of running another C# instance with SDL or any other kind of library:

```
    private void RunSDLProgram()
    {
        FileInfo spectrumFileInfo = new FileInfo("pathToFile.exe");
        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(spectrumFileInfo.FullName);
        info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        info.RedirectStandardError = true;
        info.UseShellExecute = false;
        info.WorkingDirectory = spectrumFileInfo.DirectoryName;
        pVizualizer = new Process();
        pVizualizer.StartInfo = info;
        pVizualizer.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        pVizualizer.Exited += new EventHandler(myProcess_Exited);
        pVizualizer.Start();
    }

    private void myProcess_Exited(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
            $"Exit time    : {pVizualizer.ExitTime}\n" +
            $"Exit code    : {pVizualizer.ExitCode}\n" +
            $"output    : {pVizualizer.StandardOutput}\n" +
            $"err    : {pVizualizer.StandardError}\n" 
            );
    }
```

Running a batch file will look at it's own directory and makes all references local, but it won't alter the working directory. (already had my suspicions about changing the work directory but I didn't see a way to call 2 opperations in `process.start("cmd.exe");`)

Answer (score 2):

A general way of analyzing startup issues is to use [SysInternals Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon).

Record the application that is not starting up properly. Use a filter for your application. Then go through all items which don't have `SUCCESS` in the result column. Typically you want to do that bottom-up, since the last error is the one stopping your application from loading.

Like this you'll find common startup issues like:

- missing DLLs or other dependencies
- old DLLs or DLLs loaded from wrong location (e.g. registered COM components)
- wrong working directory, e.g. access to non-existent config files